# Method not returning value of string from spinner item, returning null, android

Tags: android, android-spinner

The following code returns a `null` value. Can anyone please tell me why?  I'm looking to use the returned value to send it to another activity in an intent the `Choice` string is declared in the class this code belongs to:

```
 public String SetupBreakfastSpinner()
{
    Choice = "";
    SpinnerSelector= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(HomeActivity.this, R.array.breakfastArray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    SpinnerSelector.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    Breakfast.setAdapter(SpinnerSelector);
    Breakfast.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Choice= parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        }


        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
        return Choice;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To expedite getting the help you want, please take a few minutes to visit the [help]. In particular, read through [ask] and [mcve]. If you follow these guidelines and suggestions, we will be able to help you much more easily.

Answer (score 0):

In method `SetupBreakfastSpinner` you are initializing `Choice` to empty string. When you call this method you are setting adapter to spinner correctly but immediately returning `Choice` which is still empty.

As you have to send `Choice` value to another activity, you have two options:

**Approach 1**: When user choose an Item in spinner, `onItemSelected` callback gets called:

```
 void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     Choice= parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
     //start your activity here, pass Choice value in the Intent

 }
```

**Approach 2**: Assuming that you have some button, which when clicked you start activity, in onClick of button you can start activity

```
   void onClick(View v){
       //Start activity, pass Choice in Intent
    }
```

> Keep in mind that values that changes on certain event, for example
>   here `Choice` variable gets updated when user choose values, you need
>   to be careful before using such variables, such variable might be
>   null.